# Importing a csv file using fread loses factor order

Tags: r, data.table, fwrite, fread

When I try to read a previously saved CSV file using `data.table` function `fread`, the categorical order of my data is not preserved. It gets formatted in alphabetical order.

To replicate this issue, I have created a fake dataset using `data.table`

```
dat <- data.table(name = c("Joe", "Bob", "Steve", "Lucy", "Eric", "Marshall","Henry"), 
              subject  = as.factor(c(4,1,2,3,4,3,2)))
```

Using `setattr` function, I then label the levels of the factor column named `subject`.

```
setattr(dat$subject,
    "levels",
    c("Math","Biology","Sport", "ICT"))
```

This is what the dataset looks like.

```
       name subject
1:      Joe     ICT
2:      Bob    Math
3:    Steve Biology
4:     Lucy   Sport
5:     Eric     ICT
6: Marshall   Sport
7:    Henry Biology
```

I examine the structure of the dataset and the order of the levels within the subject factor. The `subject` column is factor and levels are in the exact same order as I set them.

```
str(dat) 

   Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':   7 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ name   : chr  "Joe" "Bob" "Steve" "Lucy" ...
 $ subject: Factor w/ 4 levels "Math","Biology",..: 4 1 2 3 4 3 2
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 

as.ordered(dat$subject)

Levels: Math < Biology < Sport < ICT
```

When I save the data set using `fwrite`, and then use `fread` to open it, the `subject` column becomes a character and the levels are ordered alphabetically.

```
# save the data
fwrite(dat,
       file = "dat.csv",
       sep = "\t")

# read data
dat2 <- fread("dat.csv")

# check structure 
str(dat2)

Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  7 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ name   : chr  "Joe" "Bob" "Steve" "Lucy" ...
 $ subject: chr  "ICT" "Math" "Biology" "Sport" ...
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 

# check order of the levels in subject
as.ordered(dat2$subject)

Levels: Biology < ICT < Math < Sport
```

The situation stills persists when I use the colClasses argument and declare `subject` column as a factor.

**Question**
Why is the `fread` ( or `fwrite`) function in `data.table` not preserving the subject column as a *factor*. And when this is controlled for using the colClasses argument to specify the `subject` column as a factor, why is the hierarchical order of the levels in the `subject` column not preserved?

Comment: This is expected behavior, as you saved the factor column as character strings. When you read it again, `fread` or other data import functions have no idea of the original factor levels. If you want to preserve the attributes of the data, consider saving it as a .RDS file.

Comment: or use csvy, a csv with yaml metadata header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @mt1022 said:

> This is expected behaviour, as you saved the factor column as character strings. When you read it again, *fread* or other data import functions have no idea of the original factor levels. If you want to preserve the attributes of the data, consider saving it as a .RDS file.

Comment: This is wrong. `read.csv` will order  the factor levels alphabetically. See the difference in output between `df$subject` and `df2$subject`.

Comment: Furthermore, since R 4.0.0 the default value for the `stringsAsFactors` parameter is `FALSE`; hence `read.csv` should give character columns instead of factor columns.

Comment: @Jaap My mistake, you are absolutely correct. I should fix the issue soon

Comment: Moreover, the `rstudioapi` and `rlist` packages are not relevant to this answer.

Comment: imo, you can't really fix this unless you copy-paste @mt1022's comment

Comment: @Jaap im not sure i follow, you can edit the question if you like. might be clearer

Comment: You state that *"You can use the write.csv/read.csv function, where they will output the factor columns as factors, and when you will load them again it will preserve the order"*, which is plain wrong. Please look at the difference between the order of the levels of `df$subject` and `df2$subject`.

Comment: I suggest to edit the answer, copy mt1022's comment, and convert to wiki answer.

Comment: @zx8754 I'm not sure how to do it exactly, can you elaborate?

Comment: @DavidS click on "edit" then there is a "tick" box to make it a wiki answer.

Comment: @Jaap I edited the issue, can you validate it. I don't want to confuse readers

Comment: @zx8754 I did it, I think